# Where to define method to create related model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building my first rails application and have some questions as to where I should define my methods. My context is the following:

I have a /v1/api/orders controller that receives JSON messages containing order and lineitem information. This controller will check the JSON message and create an order. It also splits up the line items and creates line items related to the order.

Now the next step for me is to perform some checks on the line items and then create shipment records. Now I'm a little lost as to where I should define the method to create the shipment records and how to call it. I could create another method in the orders controller, but I feel like this isn't the right place.

What would be the 'best practise' place to define this method? And Should I also move the line item creation somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is that your controller should follow the Single Responsiblity Principle. If you think of this in REST terms your controller should strive to only be responsible for a single resource.

Your `OrdersController` should be responsible for CRUD:ing orders, your `ShipmentsController` shipments etc.

However you also have the concept of nested resources. Orders have many line-items and may have many shipments.

Our routes could look something like this (note that i'm omitting the `/v1/api/` prefix for brevity).

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :orders, shallow: true, except: [:new, :edit] do
    resources :line_items, except: [:new, :edit] 
    resources :shipments, except: [:new, :edit] 
  end
end
```

If we run `rake routes` you can see how this maps urls to controllers:

```
          Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                            Controller#Action
order_line_items GET    /orders/:order_id/line_items(.:format) line_items#index
                 POST   /orders/:order_id/line_items(.:format) line_items#create
       line_item GET    /line_items/:id(.:format)              line_items#show
                 PATCH  /line_items/:id(.:format)              line_items#update
                 PUT    /line_items/:id(.:format)              line_items#update
                 DELETE /line_items/:id(.:format)              line_items#destroy
 order_shipments GET    /orders/:order_id/shipments(.:format)  shipments#index
                 POST   /orders/:order_id/shipments(.:format)  shipments#create
        shipment GET    /shipments/:id(.:format)               shipments#show
                 PATCH  /shipments/:id(.:format)               shipments#update
                 PUT    /shipments/:id(.:format)               shipments#update
                 DELETE /shipments/:id(.:format)               shipments#destroy
          orders GET    /orders(.:format)                      orders#index
                 POST   /orders(.:format)                      orders#create
           order GET    /orders/:id(.:format)                  orders#show
                 PATCH  /orders/:id(.:format)                  orders#update
                 PUT    /orders/:id(.:format)                  orders#update
                 DELETE /orders/:id(.:format)                  orders#destroy
```

One key thing you should note is that all this is done with the standard CRUD verbs. If you start adding wonky stuff like `OrdersController#create_shipment` you're just doing it wrong.

However in reality sometimes the domain gets complex and its impossible to perfectly adhere to REST and the SRP - thats ok - just try to think if what you are trying to do can be done with just a regular CRUD action first.

Comment: Thanks this makes sense, but how would I invoke for example the creation of the line items from my order controller after creating the order. Right now what I do is: 

`order = create_order(params)`
`create_line_items(params[:line_items], order.id)`

Comment: If your controller really has to create everything at once.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to happen at the same time, I could create the order first, then the line items and then the shipments. I'm unsure how to go from creating my order in my orders controller to creating line items in my line items controller though. I know the orders controller is invoked because it is routed

Comment: Good you didnt fall in trap that almost everybody does with a checkout system. :-) You would do a POST /orders which returns an id or a location which is then used in POST /orders/99/line_items

Comment: Your LineItemsController#create just does @item = Order.find(params[:order_id]).line_items.new(line_item_params)

Comment: This is a veey common domain though and there should be relevant open source projects that you can browse through.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, really clarified some things for me :)